# Mysql define a column name to be selected by a sub inner query from other table

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error

I have table 1 like this

```
weight pr_1 pr_2 pr_3 pr_4 pr_5 pr_6 pr_7 pr_8 pr_9
5 41.47 49.06 54.63 49.42 45.24 54.63 45.52 30.7 44.57
6 43.19 51.73 58.81 53.87 46.1 58.81 46.39 31.56 45.43
```

And table 2 like this

```
country_name price_range
canada pr_1
united_kingdom pr_2
europe pr_3
australia pr_4
japan pr_5
europe_o pr_6
middle_east_africa pr_7
asia pr_8
latin_america pr_9
```

I am trying to run a select query that will fetch data from table 1 getting the column name to fetch data from sub query

```
SELECT IN(SELECT `price_range` FROM `ps_parcel_connect_countries` WHERE `country_name`  LIKE  'canada' ) as `price_range` FROM `ps_parcel_connect_weight_ranges` WHERE `weight`<=5
```

But when i run it in phpmyadmin it gives me error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN(SELECT `price_range` FROM `ps_parcel_connect_countries` WHERE `country_name` ' at line 1
```

Dont see any errors at line -1 very strange.

Will be very helpful if someone can point me in correct direction

Thanks

Comment: 1. See normalization

Comment: What you have is a bad schema.  You should normalize that first. Outside of that, you are using invalid syntax.  You can't use an `IN()` clause like that.

Comment: thanks mike what can be the best way to organize this data its a messed up data i recived..... this is the best way i think of organizing it any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have at least 3 tables here.  One which has your country data

```
country
-------
country_id [autoincrement]
country_name [index]
```

With example data like:

```
country_id   country_name
----------   ------------
1            Canada
2            United Kingdom
...
9            Latin America
```

One which has you weight gradations

```
weight
------
weight_id [automincrment]
weight_value [index]
```

With example data like:

```
weight_id   weight
---------   ------
1           5
2           6
```

And one which relates the countries and weights to prices

```
price_by_country_and_weight
--------
price_id [autoincrement]
country_id 
weight_id [unique index across country_id and weight_id]
price
```

With sample data like:

```
price_id    country_id    weight_id   price
--------    ----------    ---------   -----
1           1             1           41.47
2           2             1           49.06
3           3             1           54.63
...
10          1             2           43.19
11          2             2           51.73
...
18          9             2           45.43
```

You would then query like this:

```
SELECT p.price
FROM country AS c
INNER JOIN price_by_country_and_weight AS p
    ON c.country_id = p.country_id
INNER JOIN weight AS w
    ON p.weight_id = w.weight_id
WHERE
    c.country_name = 'Canada'
    AND w.weight <= 5
ORDER BY w.weight ASC
```